# Append items to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append this items to div but it didn't work...here is my code :

```
$("document").ready(function (){
  var aMenu = [{
    title: "Home",
    image: "/Icons/1.png",
    items: [
      { title: "about", w: "x", h: "y", image: "/Images/1-1.PNG" },
      { title: "feature", w: "x", h: "y", image: "/Images/1-2.PNG" },
      { title: "themes", w: "x", h: "y", image: "/Images/1-3.PNG" },
      { title: "typography", w: "x", h: "y", image: "/Images/1-4.PNG" },
      { title: "look", w: "2x", h: "y", image: "/Images/1-5.PNG" }
    ]
  }];
  var dv = ("#dvTitleMenu");
  for (i = 0; i < aMenu.length; i++) {
    $("#dvTitleMenu")
    .append("<div class='col6'><a href='#'><h2>"+aMenu(i).title+"</h2></a></div>");
  }
});
```

Comment: *What* didn't work, how? Did you get any errors? Pleas format your code and explain your question, preferably including a link to a fiddle or codepen; right now, it's impossible to tell what your issue is.

Comment: One point stands out, though: `aMenu(i)` is invalid syntax, and you probably mean `aMenu[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="dvTitleMenu"></div>
<script>
$("document").ready(function (){ var aMenu = [{
     title: "Home", image: "/Icons/1.png",
     items: [{ title: "about", w: "x", h: "y", image: "/Images/1-1.PNG" },
     { title: "feature", w: "x", h: "y", image: "/Images/1-2.PNG" },
     { title: "themes", w: "x", h: "y", image: "/Images/1-3.PNG" },
     { title: "typography", w: "x", h: "y", image: "/Images/1-4.PNG" },
     { title: "look", w: "2x", h: "y", image: "/Images/1-5.PNG" }]
     }]
    var dv = ("#dvTitleMenu");
   for (i = 0; i < aMenu.length; i++) {
   //console.log(aMenu.items.length);
   console.log(aMenu[i].items);
   $("#dvTitleMenu").append("<div class='col6'><a href='#'> <h2> "  +aMenu[i].title + "</h2></a></div> ");



   } });    
   </script>
```

http://js.do/code/70795